# EVM Contract Testing with JS issue - ReferenceError: artifact is not defined

Tags: solidity, truffle, evm

There is a problem i have with a new DAPP tutorial i'm looking at from this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=3681ZYbDSSk&t=1154s):

I have an issue from for testing of my contract. when i run the "truffle test": it returns the following error:

```
Using network 'development'.

Compiling .\contracts\Election.sol...
ReferenceError: artifact is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\DAPP\election\test\election.js:1:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:231:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:228:14)
    at Mocha.run (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:536:10)
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\lib\test.js:125:1
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

I'm wondering i can fix the issue and complete the testing. Also, Here are the details EVN detail:

Truffle v4.1.14 (core: 4.1.14)
Solidity v0.4.24 (solc-js)

Here is the Election.js

```
var Election = artifact.require("./Election.sol");

contract ("Election", function(accounts){

    it("Initialize with 2 candidates",function(){
        return Election.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            return instance.candidatesCount();
        }).then(function(count) {
            assert.equal(count,2);      
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the code for `election.js`?

Comment: var Election = artifact.require("./Election.sol");

contract ("Election", function(accounts){
 
 it("Initialize with 2 candidates",function(){
  return Election.deployed().then(function(instance) {
   return instance.candidatesCount();
  }).then(function(count) {
   assert.equal(count,2);  
  });
 });
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a typo: instead of `artifact.require`, try `artifacts.require`

Answer (score 2):

Should confirm that the path to your smart contract is correct?

`var Election = artifact.require("./Election.sol");`